# How is appropriate to say "one of the biggest/best" etc?

Tags: superlative-degree

The superlative forms imply that they are the ONLY ones.

For instance, if we say, that John is the *best* football player. We mean, he's *the* best.

So, how is it appropriate to say, "one of the best", when that phrase implies plurality.

Comment: Let's say, "one of the biggest ironies". Does this not imply that there are more ironies that are "as big as" the one referenced?

Comment: @AbhishekSha: Not necessarily.

Comment: @AbhishekSha and if it does, then what exactly is the problem? If you don't like calling it the superlative, call it the elative. It's a thing in pretty much all languages, not just English. That's how useful it is. Your very premise is wrong. Please provide evidence for it, otherwise this is a loaded question and as such off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If John is the best player (singular noun), then he is better than the rest of the players. If John and Mary are the best players (plural noun) then they are better than the other players.

Consequently, there is no problem saying that Mary is one of the best players. She is one of the players who are better than the rest.